# JMS message received at only one server

Tags: lucene, jms, websphere, clustered-index, synchronize

I'm having a problem with a JEE6 application running in a clustered environment using WebSphere ApplicationServer 8.
A search index is used for quick search in the UI (using Lucene), which must be re-indexed after new data arrived in the corresponding DB layer. To achieve this we're sending a JMS message to the application, then the search index will be refreshed. 
The problem is, that the messages only arrives at one of the cluster members. So only there the search index is up to date. At the other servers it remains outdated.

How can I achieve that the search index gets updated at all cluster members?
Can I receive the message somehow on all servers?
Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution: 
Generally, a JMS message delivered via a queue goes only to one of the cluster members. I found a possible way to get the info to all of the cluster members, using a EJB timer. Creating a non-persistent timer should call the callback method on all of the cluster members. This might be a convenient way to recreate the local search index on all the cluster members.

It is important to be a non-persistent ejb timer, because persistent timers get synchronized on the cluster and are only executed on one of the cluster members.

Comment: Additionally, the nonpersistent timer must also be automatic, and not programmatic (see IBMs docu at: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.nd.doc%2Finfo%2Fae%2Fae%2Ftejb_timerserviceejb_enh.html). Otherwise it won't run on all the cluster members at the same time.